# How to set Maximum Password Expiry in OpenLDAP Linux

Tags: openldap

I am trying to find how to change some password policy settings in OpenLDAP (on a system-wide level, not on a per user level) such that *all* LDAP account users (i.e., existing and new users) have their passwords to expire after 90 days.

I know the main parameter that controls this is the `maxPasswdAge` parameter but I am not sure how to set this. I have tried different `ldapmodify` options 
but it fails:

```
ldapmodify -W -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=mydomain,dc=local" -f test.ldif 

dn: cn=pwdpolicyentry,cn=common,cn=products,cn=OracleContext,o=my_company,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: pwdMaxAge
pwdMaxAge: 7776000
```

The error message was ..

```
modifying entry "cn=pwdpoilicyentry,cn=common,cn=products,cn=Oraclecontext,dc=mydomain,dc=com"
ldapmodify :no such object(32)

matched DN: dc=mydomain,dc=com
```

My questions are

Are there any alternatives to doing this, for example: just change a setting manually somewhere in some configuration file and restart the LDAP server.

Are there any services that need to be bounced once this is done?

Comment: How is the system using LDAP to pull this information? Is pam-ldap or nss-ldap being used?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be missing entries in the tree to the policy entry.

You will need to load the `slapo-ppolicy` overlay.  The man page for the module specifies what you need to setup.  I find the [Ztrax documentation](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/ppolicy.html) useful as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i think i already have slapo-overlay, any other thoughts please

Answer (score 0):

The tool to achieve what you need is `ppolicy`.

This a multi-step task involving:

1. a module add;
2. a schema add;
3. a overlay add to a given database (it also defines which policy entry is the default policy);
4. one or more entry adds which define the password policies (one can be the default policy).

In the entry defined at step 4 you can modify the `pwdMaxAge` attribute.

Answer (score -2):

Your "user" entry in the LDAP directory needs to have 2 attributes:

```
passwordExp: on
passwordMaxAge: 8640000
```

8640000 = 100 days.

Comment: Tim Thanks very much but how do you change these attributes , what command will you use exactly

Comment: Tim, still havent  found out how to do this , i have had no solution or reply , any more suggestions .How do i set these attributes please

Comment: which directory or config file are we talking about openldap.conf

Comment: It's not OpenLDAP related. Maybe it's a setting found on: Sun ONE Directory Server

Comment: Tim, the question is about OpenLDAP: these are not valid OpenLDAP attributes.